# when rendering why my picture is turning into purple?

Tags: rendering

I added a 2d drawing without a background which I drew in between my 3 d model. But when I am rendering it the background of the 2 d image is turning purple but the image does not. I am adding images / link of my work [image]for your reference . If anyone can help then please do.
https://pasteall.org/media/d/b/dba4fd307cbe158fb6b13646f1288a4b.blend

Comment: pink means that it can't find the original image, but if you can see it in Rendered Preview it should work...

Comment: yes i can but it is still the same @moonboots

Comment: could you please pack your image so that we can test with the real image?

Comment: maybe the image you used in the GN texture lost, pls check the exact path of the image.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/f/d/fdd6aafdbcbb7050c4b4bc0a69972d7c.blend

Comment: it is solved all , and thank you so much for your help

Comment: The channel packing wasn't succesfull only the comet image got packed. My shader editor also shows one image called `Imported-Image (1).png` which is missing.

Comment: By the way how do you upload .blend files on stackexchange?

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/ through this link @tempdevnova